# Can't run symfony commands from cron in docker

Tags: php, docker, symfony, cron

I'm trying to run cron job with symfony commands. I have this crontab.

`* * * * * cd /var/www && /usr/local/bin/php bin/console app:cron:commands > output.txt`

I tested if Cron is running by

`* * * * * cd /var/www && touch output.txt`

this worked and created file.

Then I tried if php is runnig by

`* * * * * cd /var/www && /usr/local/bin/php --version > output.txt`

this also worked and I got php version output into file output.txt

Last what I tried was

`* * * * * cd /var/www && /usr/local/bin/php bin/console about > output.txt`

and also now I got output.

I'm trying to figure it out for 2 day's I'm desperate. I can't figure out where is the problem. Symfony command run from command line just fine.

When I was writing this post I run last test I tried to create new test command and use part of the command I can't make run I think was creating problem. It works I don't know why. Difference is only in ownership of the commands. Command I can't run is owned by root and the test command I created is owned by 1000. Can this be the problem?

Edit: I changed ownership to 1000. Nothing change still didn't run from cron.

Comment: try tacking on `2> error.txt`

Comment: @Sammitch I don't understand what to do.

Answer (score 1):

This probably has the answer:
[How to use crontab to execute a Symfony command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43324413/how-to-use-crontab-to-execute-a-symfony-command)

Try this

```
* * * * * cd /var/www && /usr/local/bin/php bin/console app:cron:commands > output.txt -e prod
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. This didn't help. I'm in dev environment and even when I try with -e dev, no luck.

Comment: Have you tried this? 
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/24990529/8135271

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the docker container to run php, you might need to use the container in cron:

```
docker exec -it name_of_your_container php /var/www/example.net/bin/console about > output.txt
```